# Forms with large number of checkboxes no longer work on new server

Tags: php

I know this question is really open-ended. Recently migrated from one server to another server at the same web host. The PHP version on the old server is 5.2.8 and the new server is 5.2.17. Everything works normally except for 2 pages. Both of them have a large number of checkboxes on the page to select different attributes for a product (200 checkboxes+). These pages no longer update products when the form is submitted. There are no errors, everything seems to be working correctly except the updates in the mysql db aren't being made. Other forms on the site are working correctly.

Any ideas what this could be? I know there's not a lot to go off of here, but any ideas where to start would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: I was sure that it was going to be post max size. It always catches me out that one. I would suggest first off, print_r() the $_POST and check all your checkbox data is coming through. If it is, then dump your query and see if it is correct (by dumping it, you could also put it into phpmyadmin or an equivalent manager and directly test the query outside of the application.

Comment: I agree with @Lee (no pun intended :D). Do as he suggested and give us a feedback.

Comment: I'm using an input type="hidden" to pass a variable when the form is submitted. In the code, it checks if the hidden variable is set, if it is then it does the processing on the db. I checked and the hidden variable isn't being passed. No changes were made to the code since upgrading to the new server. Any ideas why the hidden variable isn't being passed along? I know how to fix this page specifically but there might be other forms on the site that are working incorrectly so I'd rather fix them all at once instead of going through page by page.

Comment: @Lee and Songo It has something to do with the number of checkboxes on the page. When it was over 600 checkboxes, my input type hidden variable didn't get passed along. When I reduced the number of checkboxes to about 50, then everything worked as expected.

Comment: maybe increase your memory limit  too? for the sake of testing make it far higher than you normally would. Also put your post_max_size too a stupidly high limit too. Without seeing code and/or an example it's difficult to help much more

Comment: The web host did all of that too with no luck. I'm trying to check now which php modules were installed on the old server and compare them to the new server. I'll report back with any progress. Thanks for all of the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was being caused because max_input_vars in PHP was set to 1000. I
had to increase that number in php.ini and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `post_max_size` in php.ini. It may be that you are exceeding the limit set in it.

[From the php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

> `post_max_size`
>
> Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file
>   upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than
>   upload_max_filesize. If memory limit is enabled by your configure
>   script, memory_limit also affects file uploading. Generally speaking,
>   memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size. When an integer is
>   used, the value is measured in bytes. Shorthand notation, as described
>   in this FAQ, may also be used. If the size of post data is greater
>   than post_max_size, the $_POST and $_FILES superglobals are empty.
>   This can be tracked in various ways, e.g. by passing the $_GET
>   variable to the script processing the data, i.e. , and then checking if
>   $_GET['processed'] is set.

Comment: Tried that, confirmed it in phpinfo() and it didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: @Adam are you using Apache or IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your post_max_size configuration directive in php.ini

Comment: Tried that, confirmed it in phpinfo() and it didn't change anything unfortunately.